# Displaying Unique SEO code two times in the URL when change length 2 to 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, seo, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.80

My editor is vs2015 community.

Currently default nopCommerce supporting only two character for Unique SEO code

But I need to at least five character. e.g if Vietnam English then url will be /vn-en and if Vietnam Vietnamese then url will be /vn-vi

So I am thinking to add vn-en and vn-vi in Unique SEO code.  But its supporting only two character. So i did some change in code.

1. LanguageMap.cs HasMaxLength(2) to HasMaxLength(5)
2. LanguageValidator.cs Length(2) to Length(5)
3. nvarchar(2) to nvarchar(5) in Language table

Then nop is allowing me to add five character in that field.

But when i am changing language from front store then url displaying like /vn-vi/vn-vi. Means displaying seo code two times. And I can see 404 page not found direct html code in output.

When two character in that field then working fine. I have missing some steps?

Anyone can please guide me?

Awaiting for your response

Comment: check your routing in routeprovider.cs

Comment: In this file May I know which route ?

Comment: for language there is only one route

 //change language (AJAX link)
            routes.MapLocalizedRoute("ChangeLanguage",
                            "changelanguage/{langid}",
                            new { controller = "Common", action = "SetLanguage" },
                            new { langid = @"\d+" },
                            new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });

Comment: Ohh yes that one please note that there is `\d` regex in `langid` it could be problematic because this means only digits allow in `langid` remove this regex validation or modify it accordingly

Comment: Yeah. But can you please suggest what need to change in route. 

I want like this e.g if Vietnam English then url will be /vn-en and if Vietnam Vietnamese then url will be /vn-vi

Comment: your route should be something like this `routes.MapLocalizedRoute("ChangeLanguage", "changelanguage/{langid}", new { controller = "Common", action = "SetLanguage" }, null , new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });`

Comment: I did change still same http://localhost:15536/vn-vi/vn-vi/ and <html class="html-not-found-page">

Comment: @JatinGadhiya: I think to generate it from our side, we need Language pack. can you please provide it. then we can digging with the issue.

Comment: I don't have any language pack.. may i know the process for same? I have all resource string for vn-en.. then i will add for vn-vi also... its not right way ? or some language pack available it will load vn-vi resource string automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>After investigating the issue that you're facing is because of `AddLanguageSeoCodeToRawUrl` method of `LocalizedUrlExtenstions` adding SEO code two times.</s>

I think we can make it fix to check `UniqueSeoCode` before adding it to the URL.

```
if (!url.Contains(language.UniqueSeoCode))
{
    //add SEO code
    url = url.Insert(startIndex, language.UniqueSeoCode);
    url = url.Insert(startIndex, "/");
}
```

Add if condition in `AddLanguageSeoCodeToRawUrl` method, and check!

Change `_seoCodeLength` from 2 to 5 in `LocalizedUrlExtenstions` at Nop.Web.Framework > Localization

Hope this helps!

Comment: I added condition but not working... getting message: The localhost page isn’t working

localhost redirected you too many times.

Comment: @Dv: did you checked ?